# Recommended method for handling UnsupportedEncodingException from String.getBytes("UTF-8")

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

What is the recommended way to handle an [UnsupportedEncodingException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html)  when calling String.getBytes("UTF-8") inside a library method?

If I'm reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html correctly, UTF-8 encoding should *always* be available, which leads me to believe there's no reason to pass this exception on to the library's consumer (that is, add a `throws` clause to the method signature). It seems any failure mode that made UTF-8 encoding facilities unavailable would be catastrophic, leading me to write this handler:

```
    try
    {
        ....
        return "blah".getBytes("UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        // we're assuming UTF-8 encoding is always available.
        // see
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null; //prevent compile-time "method must return a result" errors
    }
```

Is there a failure mode that wouldn't be addressed by this snippet?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as the question it's supposed to be a duplicate of involves URL encoding/decoding.  I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 55):

You know what I do?

```
return "blah".getBytes( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );
```

This one doesn't throw a checked exception.

**Update**: Since Java 1.7, we have [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).

```
return "blah".getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the problem altogether. :) Marking this as an answer doesn't seem completely correct, though...

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Charset.forName throws an unchecked exception, which is what UnsupportedEncodingException should have been to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this question while trying to figure out if UTF-8 is always available.  So thanks for the link.

I agree that there is no need to throw a **checked** exception when it comes to encoding and decoding using a specific character set that is guaranteed to be available.  If the character set was a variable that was passed in, I would probably throw UnsupportedEncodingException.

This is what I am doing in a similar piece of Android code:

```
public static String encode(String input) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(input, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

`CharEncoding.UTF_8` is just Apache Commons' String constant for "UTF-8".

Judge Mental's suggestion to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` is great but for those of us doing Android development, it's only available on SDK 19 (KitKat) and above.

Comment: If StandardCharsets is not available, there's nothing stopping you from writing your own `MyStandardCharsets` class with some `public static final Charset`s initialized using `Charset.forName`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lombok, @SneakyThrows annotation can be used to avoid this.

**From Lombok documentation:**

"@SneakyThrows can be used to sneakily throw checked exceptions without actually declaring this in your method's throws clause.

- An 'impossible' exception. For example, new String(someByteArray, "UTF-8"); declares that it can throw an UnsupportedEncodingException but according to the JVM specification, UTF-8 must always be available. An UnsupportedEncodingException here is about as likely as a ClassNotFoundError when you use a String object, and you don't catch those either! "

https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows